# ElasticSearch intermittent blank responses (cluster status: yellow)

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch (based off of Lucene) for searches.  Every now and then over the past month or so since switching, I have had users get no results on a query.  If they refresh, the results will be populated.  Looking into the log I don't see any errors, so I am assuming that ElasticSearch just can't access the index on occasion.

This isn't when I am indexing large amounts of documents either.  Is there something I can add to the settings that will help me better debug this?  Would it help to tweak the configuration or add another cluster or node?

If I check my Admin Cluster Health, it is a yellow status.  Would resolving this help my issue?

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "xxxxx",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 5,
  "active_shards" : 5,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 5
}
```

Comment: Do the users get no results while you are indexing (new results)? Yellow state means that not all the shards can be allocated, as you have a single node and the replica shards cannot be allocated on the same node where the primaries are located. Not related to the issue you describe.

Comment: @javanna there seems to be no correlation when I am indexing new items and the users receiving no results.  I can search fine when I am indexing, and the times that no results have been displayed (and fixed with a re-search) were not necessarily when we were indexing.  I'll look into the yellow status on an unrelated note, thank you.

Comment: how does the users query the index?

Comment: @runarM Through a web interface that makes a PHP cURL request to 'http://localhost:9200/xxxx/yyyy/_search' with a complex query DSL to filter and weight their results.  It shouldn't be due to invalid query DSL though, because every time it has failed a couple refreshes (same query) will fix it.

Comment: And the result of the query is a ok response with 0 hits? With no failures of any kind?

Comment: Sorry, @runarM I thought I responded already. No failures and can't see anything in the logs (I have default log settings).